# Autofocs not working on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, razor

I wrote this line in my view at the beginning of the year

```
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ItemID, new { htmlAttributes = new { autofocus = "autofocus" } })
```

It worked fine on both Firefox and Chrome for setting autofocus to that field. I revisited this page recently and I see that autofocus is no longer being set on Chrome. It works perfectly fine on Firefox still.

Any ideas on how I could alter this code to get it to work again. Perhaps there is some extension for Chrome I could use instead

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the autofocus attribute. [Refer documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

The equivalent for EditorFor (using MVC-5.1+ only) is obtained with the following syntax:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { autofocus = "autofocus" } })
```

Or you can do that using jQuery:

```
<div class="editor-field focus">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div> 
$(function() {
    $('.focus :input').focus();
});
```